# TwitterBootstrapMVC Could not load file or assembly 'Portable.Licensing, Version=1.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/ to work:

- MVC 5, .NET 4.51
- NuGet 2.85
- Installed via NuGet TwitterBootstrapMVC5
- Followed instructions to get a licence file and installed it in the root of the application as described
- Verified that all expected    packages are installed:

_

```
PM> install-package TwitterBootstrapMVC5
Attempting to resolve dependency 'T4MVCExtensions (≥ 3.6.5)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Portable.Licensing (≥ 1.1.0)'.
'TwitterBootstrapMVC5 3.13.10' already installed.
MyApp.Web already has a reference to 'TwitterBootstrapMVC5 3.13.10'.

PM> install-package Portable.Licensing
'Portable.Licensing 1.1.0' already installed.
MyApp.Web already has a reference to 'Portable.Licensing 1.1.0'.
```

However as soon as I load a view with the helper in it I get:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Portable.Licensing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Exception: Could not load file or assembly 'Portable.Licensing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

Line 7:

Line 8:

Line 9: @using (var f = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Form()))
Line 10: {
Line 11: @f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(x => x.AbbreviationCode).Placeholder("Abreviation Code")
```

Any ideas what I need to do so that it finds the licensing assembly?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue and fixed it by referencing the **Portable.Licensing.dll**